# PowerShell - Visual Studio Code - How to disable 'more' on long results?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, help-system

I keep having to hit the enter key when the results are longer than my screen in Visual Studio Code.

**Example**
Get-Help Remove-Item - detailed

[image]

How can I get all the results on the screen without having to hit enter on 'more' please?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Note: The following applies to *all* PowerShell hosts (environments), not just Visual Studio Code.</sup>

**The `Get-Help` cmdlet itself does *not* perform interactive pagination** (waiting for a keypress before printing the next page).

However, **the built-in `help` *function* does**: it (ultimately) pipes to the `more.com` utility (on Windows); you can inspect the function definition with `$function:help`.

If you're really seeing pagination with `Get-Help`, the implication is that a *custom command* is shadowing the `Get-Help` *cmdlet* (e.g., hypothetically, a `Get-Help` *function* defined in your `$PROFILE` file).

Use `Get-Command -All Get-Help` to investigate the problem: if there are multiple results, they are shown in order of precedence; that is, the effective command is shown first.

---

**If you do want the `help` command to act like `Get-Help` - i.e. *without* pagination - you can define a `help` *alias***, as [shown in this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/268304/how-do-i-disable-paging-of-help-in-powershell):

```
New-Alias help Get-Help
```

Since an alias has a higher command-lookup precedence than a function  (see [`about_Command_Precedence`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Precedence)), the `help` alias effectively overrides the built-in `help` function.

If you put the above command in your `$PROFILE` file, `help` will act like `Get-Help` in all sessions (except those started with `-NoProfile`).
Note that Visual Studio Code's PowerShell extension has its own `$PROFILE` file, distinct from that of PowerShell sessions in regular console windows.